# Reeplazar espacios por _

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Lo que quiero intentar hacer es cambiar los espacios en la url del usuario por `"_"`, y si el usuario busca por ejemplo, `Nombre_Apellido` que busque el usuario que desea, sin necesidad de poner el espacio.

En la base de datos el objeto `characterName` contiene espacios, pero quiero que en php esos espacios lo reemplaze por un `"_"`.

```php
function find_user_by_id($id){
    try{
        $find_user = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE characterName= ?");
        $find_user->execute([$id]);
        if ($find_user->rowCount() === 1){
            return $find_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y esta otra función es de búsqueda.

```php
<?php
require 'includes/init.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $user_data = $user_obj->find_user_by_id($_GET['id']);
}
?>
```

Lo que me refiero es que en ves de buscar en el enlace `http://localhost/personajes/Nombre%20Apellido` poder buscar en el enlace `http://localhost/personajes/Nombre_Apellido`, y al intentar buscar ese nombre y apellido necesite el `_`.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases 2 parámetros en tu url y luego los concatenes en uno solo, tu url pudiera quedar asi `http://localhost/personajes/user_profile.php?nombre=juan&apellido=perez` o asi `http://localhost/personajes/juan/perez`

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Podrías usar un **str_replace()** en el `$id` para buscar directamente en la base de datos con los espacios.

Con el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver que se reemplaza `'_'` por `' '` y con ese nuevo `$id` puedes realizar la búsqueda en la base de datos

```php
$id= "Nombre_Apellido";
$id = str_replace('_', ' ', $id);
print_r($id);
```